# Content slider like a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have almost identical content slider like [this one](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/12/lightest-jquery-content-slider-ever-made-380-bytes/):

How could I make it rotate automatically? I have tried different ways but I cant make it work. I have tried putting a click on the link but it doesn't work:

```
i=1;
function autoplay(){
$('#navPoveznica'+i).click();
i++;
if(i>5){i=0};
setTimeout(autoplay, 2000);
}
```

And I called the function when DOM was `.ready()`
I'm really out of ideas, why doesn't this work? Can I select this way?
Should I use the class of the link and `.each()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine for me. Please check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/5f8dM/).

Please paste your html,js fully so that we can have a check or set it up in jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah it works! My didnt work because i was calling the function befor i declared it :O thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make an array of all the divs that needs to be slided like

```
//Define Variables
var divArray = [];
var delay: 6000;
var autoPlay: true;
var totalDivs: 5;
i = 1;

function createDivArray(){
    $('#content_slider_container').find("div").each( function () {
        divArray.push(this.attr('id'));
    });
}
```

Then Write an AutoPlay Function Like this:

```
function autoPlay(divArray) {
  ContentSlider = setInterval(function play(){
      $(divArray).eq(i).slideLeft();
      if (i >= totalDivs){
        i = 0;
      } else {
        i++;
      }
    }
  }, options.delay);
```

and Run the function like

```
autoPlay(divArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems that my original code works. Cheers